# continuing and injective transformation

Tags: general-topology, transformation

Does exist continuing and injective transformation B->A ?
Are they homeomorphic?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There exists a continuous injective map $B\to A$ (remove the lower edge of $A$ to see it). $A$ and $B$ are not momeomorphic, however, because it is possible to remove 5 points from $A$ and obtain 8 connected components whereas removing 5 points from $B$ produces at most 7 connected components (why?).

Comment: The second answear is clear:)
But the first one... I can see it, but how to write it?